# How to set localstorage in selenium + node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set local storage using nodeJs + selenium. Actually I tried with Java + Selenium with the below code it works well for me.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("localStorage.setItem(arguments[0],arguments[1])", "Id", "{\"_expired\":0,\"_value\":\"133\"}")
```

But, unable to achieve the same thing using nodeJs, Already tried some methods like-

```
localStorage.setItem('Id', '{\"_expired\":0,\"_value\":\"133\"}');
```

but Instead of putting in browser local storage, it is writing on some local files.

[LocalStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Led8n.png)

I want to set key and value in Application >> Local Storage >>{site url}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below snippet. Hope it will work!

```
driver.executeScript(function () {
    localStorage.setItem("Id", '{\"_expired\":0,\"_value\":\"133\"}');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access browser's `localstorage` from node JS.

You can use this package [`Store`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/store) for your job  though,

```
const store = require('store');
store.set('myObj', { name:'foo' })
 
// Get myObj
store.get('myObj')
```

Comment: Thank you @ABGR . Actually, I am new to node js if possible can you plz elaborate your answer: - I installed the store.js using "npm install store" after that put the code const store = require('store');
store.set('myObj', { name:'foo' })  .Then I run the script and open, the developer tool of that particular session checks the application>>local storage>>{siteurl} but nothing is updated.

Comment: Yeah you wont get that on broswer's localstorage. They are only meant for client-side JS. You can get `store.get('myObj')` on your server side node-js code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
driver.executeScript(
        "localStorage.setItem(arguments[0], arguments[1])", key, value
    );
```

Comment: Can you add some context about what this does?

Comment: This code set your local storage.

Example:

`    
   function setLocalStorage(driver, key, value) {
        return driver.executeScript(
            "localStorage.setItem(arguments[0], arguments[1])", key, value
        );
    }
    `